# How can I find out how much space is used by my container images from the Google Container Registry

Tags: docker, containers, gcloud, google-container-registry

I have pushed container images using `gcloud docker push` to the Google Container Registry. Two questions:

How do I see how much space all my images use? (I can see individual images but I want a total in order not to navigate to all and make a sum)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good questions!

All your Docker images are stored in a [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) bucket called `artifacts.<PROJECT-ID>.appspot.com` (Replace `<PROJECT-ID>` with your project's ID)

To find the total space, run `gsutil du gs://artifacts.<PROJECT-ID>.appspot.com`

Comment: Ok there seems to be a problem with the saved images. After deleting all my images from the registry, the storage (artefacts -> containers -> images) is still full of dozens of image folders.

Comment: Yes, these are the Docker layers that are stored. How did you delete your images? You should delete these as well.

Comment: Is there a place we can request for this to be added?  I'd rather not store some of my images indefinitely and I definitely don't want to wipe out my entire bucket

Comment: @anztenney I'm looking into it!

Comment: @SandeepDinesh The only way I see that I can delete the images is by visiting each one and removing all the tags. The warning tells me (indirectly) that the images would not be accessible anymore without any tag. I also want to delete them but I see now way how to do it in another clean way.