# How can I cleanly remove a container image from the Google Container Registry?

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-container-registry

I have pushed container images using `gcloud docker push` to the Google Container Registry. Two questions:

How do I cleanly remove a pushed container image from the registry? (I know I can remove a tag to an image and make it not accessible anymore.)

There are a bunch of Docker layers that an image brings with it. I want to remove all the unused layers with an image deletion.

Comment: This question originated from http://stackoverflow.com/q/33671369/454103. There are some partial answers that do not completely solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a pushed image in Google Container Registry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523945/how-to-remove-a-pushed-image-in-google-container-registry)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE:** You can now delete individual container images straight from the UI.

1. Go to the [Container Registry page](https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/images/list).
2. You should see a list of container images. Click the one you want to delete.
   [image: Container Registry]
3. Select one or more tags, and click the delete button. 
   [image: Select and Delete images]

<s>**As of Nov 2015:** There is no way to currently delete a single container image from the registry cleanly. Right now, it is basically all or nothing. The GCR team is working on this!</s>

**Original Answer:** I can't think of an easy way to delete individual images. You can delete ALL of the images by deleting the Cloud Storage bucket with `gsutil rb gs://artifacts.<PROJECT-ID>.appspot.com`. You can also use the storage browser and try to delete individual parts (https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/artifacts..appspot.com) but you would have to know the Docker hashes for each layer!

Comment: Thanks @sandeep-dinesh. I will leave this question then open maybe someone a bit later posts the solution when this will be implemented.

Comment: Just updated my answer, you can now delete individual images from the UI.

Comment: Looks great now. I will make some tests to see how it also works. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This can be done via Gcloud which means it can be done from the CLI or in a code pipeline (say at the end of CD).

As [documented by Google](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/delete), you can collect a list of all untagged images with:

```
gcloud container images list-tags  [HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE] --filter='-tags:*' --format="get(digest)" --limit=$BIG_NUMBER
```

And then delete an image with:

```
gcloud container images delete  [HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]@DIGEST --quiet
```

where the above command is run for each output (DIGEST) from the first command.

A rough scripted example would be running the following post gcloud auth:

```
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/myProject/myApp --filter='-tags:*' --format="get(digest)" --limit=10 > tags && while read p; do gcloud container images delete "gcr.io/myProject/myApp@$p" --quiet; done < tags
```

A Github actions post CD image cleanup task would look like:

```
    needs: [CI, Build_myApp]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'Authenticate to Gcloud'
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
        with:
          project_id: myProject
          service_account_email: myServiceAccount@myProject.iam.gserviceaccount.com
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.CONTAINER_ADMIN_NP_SA }}
          export_default_credentials: true
      - name: 'Cleanup untagged images in nonprod'
        run: gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/myProject/myApp --filter='-tags:*' --format="get(digest)" --limit=10 > tags && while read p; do gcloud container images delete "gcr.io/myProject/myApp@$p" --quiet; done < tags
```

Comment: great answer! I have 80 containers without tags, so the script can't find the containers. Can you help with a same kind of script where I first can tag all the container-entries with a tag, e.g. "READYTODELETE"? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
PROJECT="project"
REGISTRY="registry"

while true; do
  echo "\n"
  DIGEST=$(gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/$PROJECT/$REGISTRY --format="get(digest)" --limit 1)
  if [ "$DIGEST" = "" ]; then
    break;
  fi  
  gcloud container images delete gcr.io/$PROJECT/$REGISTRY@$DIGEST --force-delete-tags --quiet
done
```